# How to center-align content with the left border of a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work around a library implementation of a React FE component.

I can freely change the CSS of the elements but not the HTML structure, which looks as follows:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="innermost">
            <! –– my custom html content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like:

```
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1; /* stretch full width */
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative:
    min-height: 70px;
}

.innermost {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

I'd like to move my custom html content such that it is center-aligned (horizontally) with the *left border* of `innermost` div. **The content won't have any specified width/height**.

[image: problem example]

Note: Padding in image is for representational purposes only (such that each div can be made visible)

Comment: center aligned with left border ? you mean....vertically centered ?

Comment: horizontally centered

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-items: center;` CSS property in the `.inner` class. It should fix your problem.

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1; /* stretch full width */
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative:
    min-height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
}

.innermost {
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="innermost">
            <! –– my custom html content -->
            Test Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this center-aligns the content with `.inner` which isn't what I'm looking for. I've updated the question with an image to help represent it better

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inner {
    position: relative:
}

.innermost {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```